# Why would my notebook only turn on after several attempts?

Tags: boot, power, intel-core2, fsb, intel-celeron

It was working perfectly fine until I changed it's *Celeron* processor for a *Core 2 Duo* today. Now it only turns on 1 out of 5 or 6 attempts. Sometimes at the 1st or 2nd attempt. It's pretty random by the way.
This is what happens:

1. I press the power button and I hear the fan and the LEDs light up. But it won't turn on. There's no *beeps*, no bios, not even screen backlight.
2. I turn it off (by pressing the power button for ~5 seconds) and turn it on again, but still nothing.
3. I repeat steps 1 and 2 until it finally *turns on correctly*.
4. Once turned on it works perfectly fine: there's no lag, no overheating, no failures, nothing.

This also happens when I reboot it: it turns off normally but it won't turn on again and I have to repat steps `1` through `3` until I reach `4`. Once it's on, it works perfectly fine.

Temp is about 48° Celsius when idle and maxing at about 71° (the `sensors` command says that critical temp. is +100°), so I don't think temperature is the issue. I've even tried letting it cool down completely but it doesn't make a difference.

**Additional information**:

The new CPU's FSB clock rate (800 MHz) isn't the same as that of my old processor (533 MHz), but as far as I know if that were the issue it shouldn't be able to turn on at all, no matter how many attempts I tried.

The `lshw` command indicates that I have a `PM965/GM965/GL960` chipset, each one supporting an [800 MHz FSB](http://ark.intel.com/products/29822/intel-82pm965-memory-controller), an [800 MHz FSB](http://ark.intel.com/products/29821/intel-82gm965-graphics-and-memory-controller), and a [533 MHz FSB](http://ark.intel.com/products/29830/intel-82gl960-graphics-and-memory-controller), respectively, according to what the Intel ARK pages say. So I don't know for sure which is the one that my motherboard has, since this processor has an [800 MHz FSB](http://ark.intel.com/products/29761/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7500-4M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) and it works fine once it has turned on. This is the output of `lshw`:

```
/0/100        bridge     Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub 
/0/100/2      display    Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) 
/0/100/2.1    display    Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
```

My notebook doesn't have any battery, so it's always running on the AC, in case you wonder.

**Update**:

It seems that the problem has somehow settled down: now only 1 out of 10 attempts fail. I still can't find any logical explanation for this.

Comment: What is the model of laptop? Did you check the compliance of CPU and motherboard?
Did you check list of exceptions or errata or non-compliance with some chipsets?
Are you able to check the previous CPU (if returned) work fine back again? Just in case, probably "walking contact" appeared somehow in there(or shortage).

Comment: Okay, I'll translate what I've found: 

Since it has the GL960 chipset, it'd admit processors like Celeron M, Pentium Dual-Core with a FSB of 533 MHz. 
For example 
Intel® Pentium® Processor T2390 (1M Cache, 1.86 GHz, 533 MHz FSB) 

Source: http://h30467.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-para-notebooks/Cambio-de-procesador-en-presario-c700-C792EM/m-p/238841/highlight/true#M26122

And I've found out that this Core 2 Duo T7500 has an FSB of 800 MHz. So why does it even turn on? Also, what does "walking contact" mean? Thank you!

Comment: Also, the `lshw` command indicates a PM965/GM965/GL960 chipset, supporting an 800 MHz FSB, an 800 MHz FSB, and an 533 MHz FSB, respectively. So I don't know for sure which one is the one my motherboard has, since this processor has an 800 MHz FSB and it runs fine (except for the power-on). And another thing, my laptop doesn't have any battery so it's always running on the AC.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this post but for the record: it seems as if it works normally now, around 9 out of 10 attempts it would turn on normally, as if it had "settled down". Weird.